# edit css to event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make background change CSS attribute to `event.target` and it is not working. All the commands are working except changing event.target.css

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".plusMatch").click(function(event) {

        if ($("#productImage"+event.target.id).hasClass("visible")) {
            $("#productImage"+event.target.id).css("display", "none");
            $("#productImage"+event.target.id).removeClass('visible');
            event.target.css("background", "url(minusSign.jpg)");

        } else {
            $("#productImage"+event.target.id).css("display", "block");
            $("#productImage"+event.target.id).addClass('visible');
            event.target.css("background", "url(minusSign.jpg)");
        }


    });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first thing is that you are using JQuery in your project, so it is better for you to write `$(event.target)` instead of `event.target` **if you want to use the JQuery CSS property**.

Then, to change any CSS property with javascript, you have two options :

**The native style property** will edit the style tag on your HTML element, for example :

```
event.target.style.background = 'url(myPicture.jpg)';
```

[More informations](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)

**The JQuery css property**

```
$(event.target).css('background': 'url(myPicture.jpg)');
```

[More informations](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Both of these solutions will produce the following result :

```
<div style="background:url('myPicture.jpg');"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`event.target` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Either make a jQuery object or use the native DOM `.style` API.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `$(event.target).css(...)` because `event.target` is DOM element, not a jQuery Object. Use $ to convert to jQuery Object:

```
$(event.target).css("background", "url(minusSign.jpg)");
```

Alternatively, use `.style` on the regular DOM element:

```
event.target.style.background = "url(minusSign.jpg)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this line:

```
event.target.css("background", "url(minusSign.jpg)");
```

to:

```
$(event.target).css("background", "url(minusSign.jpg)");
```